# How to aggregate statistics from requests with path variables in locust?

Tags: locust

I want to load test the following GET endpoints. I get the aggregated statistics for the first two endpoints but as the other two endpoints are different for each post and user I get the segregated result in these scenarios. Is there a way to accumulate the data from these endpoints without running the APIs separately?

```
/api/v1/posts
/api/v1/users
/api/v1/posts/{post_id}
/api/v1/users/{user_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ’name’ parameter. See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#name-parameter